# How to use RelayState request parameter as claim rule parameter

Tags: saml, adfs

I'm trying to configure authentication (SSO) with ADFS for some Service Provider system through SAML.

At the moment, the following is happening:

1. Service Provider send auth request to ADFS with filled parameters SAMLRequest and RelayState (I cannot influence the logic of forming the request and filling in the parameters).
2. ADFS accept the request, process claim rules and send request back to Service Provider.
3. Service Provider makes a redirection decision based on the received parameters generated by claim rules.

Is there any way to get RelayState parameter in claim rule, or some other way to send RelayState back to Service Provider?

Comment: Do you mean you want access to the relay state as input to a claim rule or simply that you want a mechanism for the relay state to be returned to the service provider? By default, ADFS returns the relay state along with the SAML response as HTTP Post data. This is as per the SAML specification. Relay state should be opaque to the identity provider so I'm not sure you can or should use it as input to a claim rule.